# Running javascript inconjunction submiting a request to create new records

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, controller

So i am using rails to do this.
I have a page with forms and a submit button which creates a new record for my database , and then redirects the page to a Thank you page. This is done through the controller.

However, i have this javascript which triggers when the submit button is pressed , which then updates my google spreadsheet. Which is basically this script here,
[http://railsrescue.com/blog/2015-05-28-step-by-step-setup-to-send-form-data-to-google-sheets/][1]

However, doing this has caused a lot of issues to occur which i do not want to go in detail now.
So better , i would want to ask is, how would you suggest i go about adding this javascript to my webpage? As of now , i just shoved this line

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'googlesheet' %>
```

at the bottom of the html page , and then it just trigger's when the button is pressed.

Comment: Shoved what line?

Comment: sorry, used the wrong tags to display code.
I attached my javascript basically that way, which then the javascript will do checking if the form submit has been triggered .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, you should be careful as the behavior in production might not be what you're looking for. If your JS is all getting minified (as it should be), then you're either going to have trouble serving just this one file since it won't be in the asset pipeline, or you're including it everywhere anyways.

Other than that, there's nothing fundamentally wrong with what you're doing. You might consider putting `googlesheet.js` in the `/vendor` folder instead of `/app`, since you found it online.

There are some ways to do this other than those I've listed below, but they're not particularly useful or good.

### "Proper" solution

You can include the `googlesheets.js` in the assets pipeline, which will make it available to the code that you currently have.

In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.assets.precompile += ['googlesheets.js']
```

See the Rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets

### Quick and dirty solution

If you're looking for a quick and dirty way to do this, one way is to put the JS into a view and then include that where you need it. It would look something like this:

In `/app/views/javascript/_googlesheet.js.erb`:

```
<script>
  // ... the existing code in your "googlesheet.js" file
</script>
```

Then in your main view (where you're currently calling `<%= javascript_include_tag 'googlesheet' %>`):

```
<%= raw render partial: 'javascripts/googlesheet', handlers: [:erb, :coffee], formats: [:js] %>
```